# Complex Laravel, Graphql and Lighhouse implementation

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

My question relates to how to built complex custom resolvers, and why they dont play along well with built in resolvers. I cannot find any good examples on complex resolvers, and my real life case is even more complex than this example.

I have the following schema

```
type Query {
    users: [User!]! @field(resolver: "App\\Library\\UserController@fetchAll")
    posts: [Post!]! @field(resolver: "App\\Library\\PostController@fetchAll")
    post(id: Int! @eq): Post @find
}

type User {
    id: ID!
    name: String
    posts: [Post!]!  @field(resolver: "App\\Library\\PostController@fetchAll")
}

type Post {
    id: ID!
    content: String!
    comments: [Comment] @field(resolver: "App\\Library\\CommentController@fetchAll")
}

type Comment {
    id: ID!
    reply: String!
commentRating: [CommentRating] @field(resolver: “App\\Library\\CommentRatingController@fetchSum")
}

type CommentRating {
    id: ID!
    rating: String
}
```

And for instance I have this query

```
{
  users {
    id,
    name
    posts {
      title
      comments {
        id,
        reply
        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need custom resolvers, because of business logic, but not for all of them. The above works(I use custom resolvers on purpose for all of them, I’ll explain in a bit) but only if I build my
eloquent query in the first resolver that gets called, correctly. Like so

```
// Function in custom resolver. All other custom resolver which are accessed can just pass the $rootValue on, or operate on it.
public function fetchAll($rootValue, array $args, GraphQLContext $context, ResolveInfo $resolveInfo)
{
// We have some more sophisticated logic to dynamically build the array parameter on the line below, because the query may not always request comments, which means 'posts.comments' wont be needed. As this is the entrypoint, $rootValue is empty
    $t = User::with['posts', 'posts.comments', 'posts.comments.ratings'])->get();

    // Business logic modules called here
        return $t;
}
```

If I start with a custom resolver, but something in the query uses a built-in resolver, for instance, if change

```
type User {
    id: ID!
    name: String
    posts: [Post!]!  @field(resolver: "App\\Library\\PostController@fetchAll")
}
```

to

```
type User {
    id: ID!
    name: String
    posts: [Post!]!  @all
}
```

Then it still runs correctly but the N+1 issue gets introduced. So I can see in my mysql log that multiple queries are being run all of a sudden, where that does not happen if I have only custom, or only built in resolvers. Is it bad practice to let a custom resolver call a built-in resolver?

Is it best to just stick to custom resolvers for all of my types? And is my approach to build the custom resolver the way I do correct? (refer to the public function fetchAll codesnippet)

Comment: build in resolver can't know, what is happening in your resolvers.
To solve N+1 Problem built in resolvers use batch loading capabilities (it kinda collect all IDs needed, bevor query is sent to DB). I don't know, if its possible to reuse them in your custom resolvers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit of a late answer but the problem was that I did not completely understand the graphql model. The custom resolvers purely need to send back a model of the correct type so that the schema can understand it. My resolvers wasn't returning with the correct types.

Answer (score 2):

you can map your resolver class in your schema like

```
type Query {
    users: [User] @field(resolver: "App\\GraphQL\\Queries\\User@FooFunction")
}
```

and generate this query resolver class with this cammand:

```
php artisan lighthouse:query User
```

and put every query you like that on this function called FooFunction:

```
<?php

namespace App\GraphQL\Queries;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\ResolveInfo;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Support\Contracts\GraphQLContext;

class User
{
    /**
     * Return a value for the field.
     *
     * @param  null  $rootValue Usually contains the result returned from the parent field. In this case, it is always `null`.
     * @param  mixed[]  $args The arguments that were passed into the field.
     * @param  \Nuwave\Lighthouse\Support\Contracts\GraphQLContext  $context Arbitrary data that is shared between all fields of a single query.
     * @param  \GraphQL\Type\Definition\ResolveInfo  $resolveInfo Information about the query itself, such as the execution state, the field name, path to the field from the root, and more.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function FooFunction($rootValue, array $args, GraphQLContext $context, ResolveInfo $resolveInfo)
    {
        return
            DB::table('...')
              ->where(...)
              ->get();
    }
}
```

Comment: that's didn't help you?

Answer (score 0):

Lighthouse provide directives like @hasOne, @hasMany, @belongsTo which prevent N+1 problem. All you need to do is use them.

https://lighthouse-php.com/master/eloquent/relationships.html#avoiding-the-n-1-performance-problem

Comment: Yes, but where would the business logic go then? My understanding is that the custom resolvers are for when you want to use business logic. I could not figure out where business logic go using built-in resolvers.